# How to use JSON Utility to Import Data from Browser to Unity?

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

I am just getting started programming and I couldn’t wrap my head around the following problem I currently have:

I have a PHP Script which retrieves the CPU Temperature of a Raspberry Pi and shows it on a local Network in my browser. The output in my browser is just a blank page with the value e.g. 56.7 only and no more.

What I would like to know now is, if it’s possible with JSON Utility to take this value and import it into Unity -> to be more specific, into an Augmented Reality Environment using Vuforia, even if it’s on a local Network and the only output is just the temperature value.

Is there anyone who could answer these (probably trivial) questions and eventually could show me how the code could look like?

And is it correct to assume, that the value within Unity would change as soon as the value in my browser changes?

I would like to thank everyone in advance for any help at all and even though these questions seem obvious for experienced programmers, I wasn’t able to find a correct answer by now.

Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

Use UnityWebRequest to contact your Raspberry Pi.

Parse the DownloadHandler.text any way you like.  JSON Utility is one option for parsing the result,  but it might be overkill if this is a hobby project that just gets one sensor value.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTextBinaryData.html

To parse the json with JsonUtility, you would make a class to hold the data, making sure to mark it with Serializable attribute.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class MyData
{
    public float temperature;
}
```

And then parse it like this, in the RetrievingTextBinaryData example

```
MyData myData = JsonUtility.FromJson<MyData>(www.downloadHandler.text)
```

Assuming your JSON looks like this

```
{ "temperature":30.7 }
```

Note: to make it continuously poll your Raspberry Pi for updates, you would need to download the temperature in the Update() method instead of Start() like in the example code.

Comment: Hello Leo, thank you first of all! I will try out what you recommended, I would also like to know how the JSON way would look like. It seems like it would be complicated and probably a lot more Code than I expected, right?

Comment: I am starting to understand it now! As soon as I set everything up, I will try it out. Thanks! But one question is still left: As I said, it’s just a regular php Script and the output is just a blank page with only the temperature (e.g. 45.7). There is no text or anything else at all. Would this still work? Or do I have to name it „Temperature: 45.7“? This is exactly the point I couldn’t understand -> How does the JSON know which value to pull. I assume a simple php script with an output of just a float won’t give me the result. These questions are probably strange, but I hope you understand.

Comment: If you view source of the page your php serves, that is the text you will need to parse in unity.  So if its just a number, you don't need to use JSON, you can just use`float.parse()`.   If its inside html tags, you can use `string.indexOf` and `string.split()` or a regex to cut out just the number so you can float.parse it.  If you use json_encode() in php, it pulls "temperature" from the name of the property on the object in php. `$obj->temperature = 30; echo json_encode($obj);`

Comment: There are some php libraries out there that make it easier to write JSON APIs in php, btw.  For exampe: https://github.com/AlexisTM/Simple-Json-PHP